# reading a log with dashed lines into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a tricky log file that I wish to to get into a clean DF. The format of the log is the following ;

```
===============================================================================
2016/03/28 12:26:45 - Message
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016/03/28 12:26:45 - Message
2016/03/28 12:26:45 - Message
Message
2016/03/28 12:26:45 - Message
2016/03/28 12:26:46 - Message
2016/03/28 12:26:46 - Message
2016/03/28 12:28:30 - Message
2016/03/28 12:28:40 - Message
2016/03/28 12:28:40 - Message
2016/03/28 12:28:40 - Message
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016/03/28 12:28:40 - Message
===============================================================================
```

The log continues in the above pattern, my goal is to have the following dataframe;

```
Time                 Text
2016/03/28 12:26:45  Message
```

I have tired to parse the file file on the '-' and create a Dataframe, and remove the dashed lines.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

clean = open(filename).read().remove('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------', '')
clean2 = open(filename).read().replace('===============================================================================', '')
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep = "\s*\-", names = ["Time", "Text"], engine = "python")
df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time, format='%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S.%f')
df.Text = df.Text
```

However I get alot of NaN columns, any help is appreciated

Comment: Double dash lines are only in start of file and in the end of file?

Comment: They are in the start and end of every section, so in the log file there are many instances of double dash files, the log file follows the pattern that I've specified in the post, so this pattern occurs multiple times in the file @jezrael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `errors='coerce'` for replace bad data to `NaT` with [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) for remove all rows where `NaT` in column `Time`:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""===============================================================================
2016/03/28 12:26:45 - Message
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016/03/28 12:26:45 - Message
2016/03/28 12:26:45 - Message
Message
2016/03/28 12:26:45 - Message
2016/03/28 12:26:46 - Message
2016/03/28 12:26:46 - Message
2016/03/28 12:28:30 - Message
2016/03/28 12:28:40 - Message
2016/03/28 12:28:40 - Message
2016/03/28 12:28:40 - Message
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016/03/28 12:28:40 - Message
==============================================================================="""
#after testing replace StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep="\s+-\s+", names = ["Time", "Text"], engine = "python")

df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time, errors='coerce') 
df.dropna(subset=['Time'], inplace=True)
```

```
print (df)
                  Time     Text
1  2016-03-28 12:26:45  Message
3  2016-03-28 12:26:45  Message
4  2016-03-28 12:26:45  Message
6  2016-03-28 12:26:45  Message
7  2016-03-28 12:26:46  Message
8  2016-03-28 12:26:46  Message
9  2016-03-28 12:28:30  Message
10 2016-03-28 12:28:40  Message
11 2016-03-28 12:28:40  Message
12 2016-03-28 12:28:40  Message
14 2016-03-28 12:28:40  Message
```

Comment: wow that works great. Can you explain sep="\s+-\s+"  and pd.to_datetime(df.Time, errors='coerce') , is that to get rid of the Message in the time column ? thanks

Comment: `sep="\s+-\s+"` means separator is multiple whitespaces with `-` and then also multiple whitespaces. And when add parameter `errors='coerce')` all data which cannot be parsed are replaced by `NaT` (it is `NaN` for datetime). So last only need dropna all rows where are `NaT` values in column time.

Answer (score 2):

A more lengthy alternative to the very nice solution of @jezrael is the following:

```
import pandas as pd

infile = "test.txt" #this is your file

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Time','Text'])

with open(infile, "r") as inf:
    for i, line in enumerate(inf):
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith("-") or line.startswith("="):
            pass
        else:
            if len(line.split("-")) > 1:
                df.loc[i] = pd.Series({'Time':line.split("-")[0], 'Text':line.split("-")[1]})

inf.close()
```

I am not sure though if you want the Time column translated to pd time format. If so then just add:

```
df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time)
```

at the end of the script